# Salesforce to Salesforce data migration

Tags: migration-tool, data-migration

I’m in the process of moving metadata and data from one source org to a new different target org. I’ve mostly completed moving all the metadata using ANT. I’ve moved some standalone tables of data already using data loader. However, this is a bit cumbersome using excel vlookups. Would a tool like Jitterbit be able to accomplish a full data migration from one Salesforce org to another Salesforce org? Is there perhaps another better option that could be setup quickly that can be run on demand that establishes all the object relationships and be able to be run to update changes and additions to records from all the different tables? Just looking for the best options and tools to accomplish this type of full data migration.

Comment: there are some appexchange packages that do this - Flosum, Metazoa, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ETL tools for Salesforce in the market,  All the tools are more or less the same when it comes to functionality and few are being perfectly suited for complex issues. However you would still need to map appropriate using excel functions that might not automate object relations like parent and child.

Below are few options that can be reviewd.

Data Migration - [TRUJAY](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EjVSuUAN),  [iSyncSF](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MSq5FEAT).

Metadata Deployments - Autorabit, Gearset, Copado etc.,

Also, check best practices for migrating data into Salesforce here ([i](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326326&type=1) , [ii](https://medium.com/@v.poojakaran/best-practices-for-migrating-your-legacy-data-into-salesforce-43304792d90)).

Thanks